# Defining struct containing array in C51 not allowed?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, c51

Structs containing arrays in C51 are not allowed? After defining a simple structure in my C51 program,

```
struct RingBuffer 
{
    int zero;
    int size;
    int capacity;
    char data[10]; 
};
```

I got error:`..\SOURCE\MYRINGBUFFER.H(25): error C141: syntax error near '['`. It is clear that error is on the line with a char array defined in the struct(no errors after commenting).

Am I doing something wrong here? If not, is there anyway I can achieve what I'm attempting to do?

EDIT: All the code.

```
#ifndef __MY_RING_BUFFER_H__
#define __MY_RING_BUFFER_H__
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct RingBuffer 
{
    int zero;
    int size;
    int capacity;
    char data[10]; 
};


#endif
```

Comment: How is `BUFFER_SIZE` defined?

Comment: If the compiler is not smart enough then the `+` may make it think the size as a dynamic value.

Comment: @MOehm, I suspected that, but it didn't work. In fact, the whole code only contains some includes at the top and this.

Comment: I am not sure why this question would be voted for close, or even down voted.  It adds value in the form of added insight for the users of C51 compilers on this site.  OP question is clearly and concisely presented with evidence of some prior debugging and research.  Although I originally commented that OP's answer should have been a comment, I now see that although it is short, it is a good answer.  Again concise and clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out what's wrong. **data** is a keyword in C51.

Comment: @ryyker: definitely not as an edit in the original post. It would no longer be a question then.

Comment: @Jongware - Yes, I see that  now. And in fact, it is a perfectly relevant answer for what is also a good question.  Thanks.